# Rails: sum all column elements where param1 == some value

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, sum

I want to sum all elements (e.g. price) from table column where some values (type) equal to some param (1):

Table

```
id type price
-------------
1  1    10
2  1     8
3  2     7
4  1     2
```

I think, it may be like this:

```
Table.where(:type => 1). ???
```

I need to get 20.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

```
Table.where(:type => 1).sum(:price)
```